# Have Highcharts legend update shiny table

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I have a shiny app with a `sidebarLayout`. The offer selection is a checkbox group in the side panel, the highchart is in the main panel with cumulative response rates over time by different offers and finally the table with the current response rate by offer is beneath both the offer checkbox group and cumulative response rate chart.

Ideally I would like to remove the `checkboxGroupInput` and have the `legendItemClick` in the highchart take over this functionality so that when a particular offer in the legend is clicked (and no longer visible on the chart) that the corresponding row in the shiny table is also hidden or removed.

I've tried tying the legend item to the checkbox in the shiny `checkboxGroupInput`, which works [here in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sbbL364/), but it does not work with the shiny app.

```
p1$plotOptions(series=list(stickyTracking=F,
  events=list(legendItemClick=paste("#!function(){
           if (this.visible) {
             $('input[value=",'"',"'+this.name+'",'"',"]').prop('checked',false);
           } else {
             $('input[value=",'"',"'+this.name+'",'"',"]').prop('checked',true);
           }
         }!#"))))
```

Any way I can do this?

Once again, ideally I'd like to replace the `checkboxGroupInput` with the `legendItemClick` to update my shiny table.

Comment: So I presume you have a table under the highcharts right, and what you want to do is when the legend is clicked/unclicked that table would be rendered too?

Comment: Right, and the "disabled" legend items would also be removed from the newly rendered table.